Disable "Continue with Google" popup
I recently started seeing this popup when I click on the View more comments button at the end of a conversation in reddit when browsing on Firefox Mobile. It says "Log in to view the conversation".
I'm not sure if it's ordinary JS, or the browser is showing it, or it's from the system. I've disabled the "Google Account sign-in prompts" described here - https://www.howtogeek.com/735152/how-to-turn-off-the-sign-in-with-google-prompt-on-websites/, so it shouldn't be that.
How can I disable it?


Are you logged in with Google on your phone (in Play Store or some other Google app)? As you can see the pop-up doesn't mentions any account name (which would be the case if it would be a system pop-up and you are logged in on system level). Therefore my guess is that it is pure JavaScript.

Thank you, that makes sense - I am logged in with Google on the phone. I couldn't select the popup with the uBlock picker, however

It's from the Reddit site: r/bugs - Desktop Web - Always asking to "log in to view the conversation", r/brave_brower - "Switch to app" popup is back for Reddit mobile

Can ublock block it? The picker can't detect the popup. Can it be done with a custom script?
